# Replacing the SPACE at first and last

Tags: php

I want to replace the first and last words and sentences .

I use this code.

```
$text = ' this is the test for string. ';
 echo $text = str_replace(" ", "", $text);
```

when i have use replace code .

all space is deleted and repalsed.
 any body can help me?!

i want get this:

```
this is the test for string.
```

Comment: See php `trim();` function

Comment: tank u for helping !wish u like  Tim Biegeleisen use trim function in code  Tim because i never use trim before ... anyway tank u for ur time ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want the `trim` function here:

```
$text = ' this is the test for string. ';
echo '***' . trim($text) . '***';

***this is the test for string.***
```

Just to round out this answer, if you wanted to accomplish the same thing using a replacement, you could do a regex replace as follows:

```
$out = preg_replace("/^\s*|\s*$/", "", $text);
echo '***' . $out . '***';

***this is the test for string.***
```

This approach might a good starting point if you wanted to do a regex replacement with perhaps slightly different logic.

Comment: I think this should be a comment

Comment: @BobbyAxe Well I certainly hope you won't Axe my answer :-0

Comment: heh @BobbyAxe me too :-))